# #1062 eror in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

I got a 1062 error in this code :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phppoll` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `phppoll`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `polls` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` text NOT NULL,
    `description` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `polls` (`id`, `title`, `description`) VALUES (1, 'What''s your favorite programming language?', '');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `poll_answers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `title` text NOT NULL,
    `votes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `poll_answers` (`id`, `poll_id`, `title`, `votes`) VALUES (1, 1, 'PHP', 0), (2, 1, 'Python', 0), (3, 1, 'C#', 0), (4, 1, 'Java', 0);
```

I don't no how fix it.

Comment: you do mean `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'poll_answers.PRIMARY'`, which means you should always copy the FULL error message.

Comment: Why, do you think, a `DUPLICATE KEY` can exist?  (Hint: run your code more than 1 time)

Comment: BTW: you are getting 2 such errors, also this one: "ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'polls.PRIMARY'"

Comment: Except for the `CREATE DATABASE`, the code runs fine in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae33bd312f9e65cb3f5f5a845e07ef7d.

Comment: In strad of doing `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....` you should do `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...` just before the `CREATE TABLE`, to make sure the table is re-recreated without records.

Comment: In your INSERT statement, remove the "id" attribute from there because it's already an auto-incremented attribute. It will be automatically generated, you don't need to input values for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arise when you run this SQL script and your target database already have the tables you want to create AND it has rows with already used ids. The `INSERT INTO` statements will fail of duplicate keys.

Depending on what you want to do or how you want to create a backup or restore it, you can use several options:

1. You can delete the existing tables, so they will be added when the SQL script is executed. They will obviously be empty when the tables are added.
2. You can delete all the existing rows in your tables. When you run your SQL script, the tables will not be created due to the `IF NOT EXISTS` part, but the tables will be empty.
3. You can create a MySQL dump with statements which will delete existing tables (and therefore delete any rows). For the `mysqldump` command, there is a setting [`--add-drop-table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-table) to do that. Other MySQL export programs might have similar options.